# Click outside div runs script

Tags: jquery, events, selector

I have this simple script and Im wondering how to make if user clicks outside of .side to hide .side.

Script is here

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".side").hide();
      $("a").click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
    });
      $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
        if (e.which == 27) {
            $("a").next().slideUp();
        }
    });
  });
```

Whole code you can find here
http://jsfiddle.net/8sn2nc3L/

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this:  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sn2nc3L/4/)

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var side = $(".side");

    if (!side.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't side...
        && side.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        side.slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain this. What is the significance of `side.has(e.target).length === 0`?

Comment: It checks to see if the target clicked was a child of the container. If it is, it will return a value greater than 0 and not run the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can check current clicked target using `$(event.target).is('.side')`. If it's false that means click is outside your div.

http://jsfiddle.net/8sn2nc3L/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".side").hide();
      $("a").click(function (e) {
          $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      });
      $(document).bind('click', function (event) {
          if (!$(event.target).is('.side')) {
              $("a").next().slideUp();
          }
      });
  });
```